# How to use custom payload enricher bean in a chain

Tags: spring-integration

I need to make some enrichment to payload by looking up or calculating some values, so far i have (looks like a workaround) below code which works fine but is there a better and more direct way to do this, thanks

Looks like there is no `method="lookup" ref="lookupBean"` available for payload enricher similair to what we have for header enricher, i could be ignorant though.

```
 <int:chain input-channel="someInputChannel">
       <int:splitter ref="spl"/>
       <int:filter ref="flb" method="filter"  discard-channel="rejectedChannel" />
       <int:transformer ref="transformer"/> 
       <int:header-enricher>
        <int:header name="lookUpData" method="lookup" ref="lookupBean"/>        
       </int:header-enricher>       
       <int:enricher>
          <int:property name="masterId" expression="headers[lookUpData]"/>
       </int:enricher>       
       <int:service-activator ref="updateAdapter" method="updateRecords"/>      
       <int:outbound-channel-adapter ref="notifierAdapter"  method="notifyUpdate"/>
   </int:chain>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SpEL:

```
  <int:enricher>
      <int:property name="masterId" expression="@lookupBean.lookup(#root)" />
  </int:enricher>
```

or

```
  <int:enricher>
      <int:property name="masterId" expression="@lookupBean.lookup(payload)" />
  </int:enricher>
```

if you only need the payload (which would mean your lookup can be a POJO an not be tied to the framework).

Comment: great but how would i pass the message as argument here to lookup(Message<?> message) in this expression. Thanks